# How do I put a opaque white gradient over a image in CSS?

Tags: css, gradient

Sorry in advance if this has been asked: I couldn't find it, but I am not so sure about my keywords I used.

Anyhow! I am trying to put an opaque white gradient line over an image. This is the stuff I am trying to put it over:

```
div.horizontal
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:45px;
}

div.horizontal ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 

div.horizontal li
{
    float:left;
}

div.horizontal a
{
    display:block;
    width:312px;
    height:35px;
    background-image: url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
}

div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
    height:45px;
    a:link {text-decoration:none;}
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
}
```

The gradient code is this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)), color-stop(52%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
```

How do I get one over the other?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
background: url("../img/truefactzheader.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: url("../img/truefactzheader.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)), color-stop(52%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
background: url("../img/truefactzheader.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: url("../img/truefactzheader.png"), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: url("../img/truefactzheader.png"), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: url("../img/truefactzheader.png"), (linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 51%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
```

but it still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gradient is considered an image in CSS 3 so just include both the gradient & the bg-image seperated by a comma in a `background` shorthand property, now that CSS 3 allows multiple background-images. Also because CSS parses from right to left, you have to specify the gradient first and *then* the image, for it to appear "over" the image.

Comment: What did you try doing? I edited my post and said to specify the gradient first *and then* the background image, did you have it that way?